# Total Container size on ECS fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs

I login ECS:fargate container and try to install a pip library (for testing)

```
root@ip-172-31-2-132:/# pip install torch
Collecting torch
  Downloading torch-1.13.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (890.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━╺━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 224.1/890.2 MB 55.4 MB/s eta 0:00:13
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

It shows error.

However, what decide the disk size of fargate?

I cheched disksystem

```
root@ip-172-31-2-132:/# df
Filesystem            1K-blocks     Used        Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                30787492 30333472                0 100% /
tmpfs                     65536        0            65536   0% /dev
shm                     3932052        0          3932052   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   3932052        0          3932052   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
127.0.0.1:/    9007199254739968  4276224 9007199250463744   1% /usr/src/app/_mat
/dev/nvme1n1           30787492 30333472                0 100% /etc/hosts
/dev/nvme0n1p1          5082764  1843908          3170064  37% /managed-agents/execute-command
tmpfs                   3932052        0          3932052   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                   3932052        0          3932052   0% /sys/firmware
```

It looks  almost all `/` are consumed, around 30GB.

then,I checked in `/` directory

```
root@ip-172-31-2-132:/# du -h -d 1
0   ./sys
3.0M    ./etc
8.0K    ./run
4.0K    ./boot
4.0K    ./lib64
4.0K    ./srv
7.0M    ./bin
304M    ./tmp
0   ./dev
4.0K    ./opt
83M ./root
4.0K    ./media
4.0K    ./mnt
4.0K    ./home
4.2M    ./sbin
271M    ./var
11G ./usr
22M ./lib
du: cannot access './proc/363/task/363/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/363/task/363/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/363/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/363/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0   ./proc
48M ./managed-agents
12G .
```

only 12G is consumed.

Moreover, I deleted some folders(like cache folder) totally 4GB manually.

and try this again `pip install torch` then it shows `[Errno 28] No space left on device` again.

Why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECS Fargate tasks by default get a total of 20GB ephemeral storage space. If you need [more than that](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/amazon-ecs-aws-fargate-configure-size-ephemeral-storage-tasks/) you need to modify the task definition to specify a larger storage amount.

Comment: Thank you very much. I decided to use EFS. So,I didn't fully install every library in container build process because it overpass 20GB,. Instead, I set `ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"] in Dockerfile  this script is  called when deploying. I installed rest of library in this scrpt. then I could deploy successfully.